# Has anyone traveled to Taiwan (ROC) on Travel Authorization Certificate (not Visa)?

Tags: visas, visa-free-entry, taiwan

Taiwan seems to have introduced a [Travel Authorization Certificate](http://www.boca.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=6464&ctNode=868&mp=2) for nationals of select countries. I seem to be eligible for this as an Indian National with Japanese Residence Card (Not permanent).

Another friend of mine, Indian and with same Japan residence card had applied (and received) for a similar Travel Certificate after confirming with the Taiwan Embassay in Tokyo. Unfortunately, he was not allowed by the airlines to board the plane because they didn't know *recognize* such a document. But that was 5 months ago, before the above mentioned policy was introduced.

I just want to know if any one else has travelled to Taiwan using the Travel Certificate recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Taiwan Travel Authorization Certificate is documented in Timatic, the system which airlines use to verify that passengers have the correct travel documents.

This is what [Timatic currently says](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&NA=IN&AR=JP&EM=IN&DE=TW&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Visa required, except for A max. stay of 30 days (not
>   applicable to holders of Emergency or Temporary Passports) for
>   nationals of India holding a Travel Authorization Certificate
>   (obtained via https://oa1.immigration.gov.tw/nia_southeast/).
>
> - Applicable to holders of a permanent Residence Permit
>     issued by Japan;
> - applicable to holders of a valid resident or visitor visa
>     (incl. electronic) issued by Australia, Canada, Ireland
>     (Rep.), Japan, Korea (Rep.), New Zealand, USA, United
>     Kingdom or a Schengen Member State. Those who
>     hold a work permit are not eligible. Resident card or visa
>     that has expired less than 10 years prior to the date of
>     arrival can still be used for entry.

I cannot tell what it said five months ago. But today it is valid if you have a permanent residence permit, residence permit or visa issued by Japan. Your friend should not be denied boarding today in similar circumstances.

Comment: Is that all Timatic says? I might not be reading it right but I'm in Taiwan right now and on an Australian passport I got 90 days visa free. It was 30 days on my previous visit 2.5 years ago though. I'm guessing you're showing just the relevant part for Indian nationals, who get different allowance in Taiwan if they have certain status with Australia.

Comment: @hippietrail I filtered Timatic only for Indian nationals with a Japanese residence permit.

Comment: @hippietrail If you want it, see [the complete visa information, unfiltered](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=TW&SUBSECTION=00&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX).